# Как сделать SVG фон для div посредством JavaScript

Tags: javascript, svg

Есть `div`.

```
<div id="myDiv1">...</div>
```

Есть JavaScript функция которая генерирует SVG.

```
function GenerateSVG() {
   ...
   return SVGtext;
}
```

Мне нужно результирующий SVG код прописать фоном этого `div`.

Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Самый простой способ:

```css
#myDiv1 {
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="10" height="10"><rect width="10" height="10" fill="red"/></svg>');
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv1">Lorem Ipsum Dolor Sit Amet Ist</div>
```